# Treatment for or treatment of?

Tags: word-usage, word-order

This study describes a treatment for/of a diseased kidney of a 15-year-old girl.

Which is correct (for or of). Does the rest also sounds alright or would it be better to rephrase the whole sentence?

This study describes a treatment for/of a 15-year-old girl's diseased kidney?

Comment: This study describes **the treatment of a** 15-year-old girl's diseased kidney. Yes, this is basically editing and not really allowed.

Comment: Prefer **treatment for** a disease / illness /etc  & treatment of **a patient / organ** Treatment of **an injury** might go either way: **The treatment for injuries to the knee is...** **Treatment of the patient's injury proved successful.**